# Step back in WizardScene telegraf

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

I am having trouble implementing the step system in my WizardScene. I've been trying for 2 days now.

**System of operation:**

The bot edits a post each time it receives the data it needs from a user.

**Required:**

Ability to go back one step from any step other than the first.

**Attempts:**

I tried to implement this via ctx.wizard.stepsctx.wizard.cursor - 2. The code was actually going backwards on the question. BUT! After the action in the previous step, the scene worked one step forward from where I returned from. That is:

1. Question: Send text.
   user: text (actually in 2 question/step).
2. Question: Send another text
   user: back (actually in 1 question/step).
3. Question: Send text.
   user: smth new (actually in 3 question/step).

**My Code:**

```
const { Scenes, Markup } = require("telegraf");

module.exports = () => {
  const scene = new Scenes.WizardScene(
    "newSceneWithStapBacks",
    async (ctx) => {
      //First step. User joined by inline callback button.
      await ctx.editMessageText(`Send text`, {
        ...Markup.inlineKeyboard([
          [Markup.button.callback(`Cancel`, `cancel`)], //Cancel button because its a first step.
        ]),
        parse_mode: "HTML",
      });

      //Creating object for data storage
      ctx.wizard.state.data = {};

      //Saving ctx with message to editing (message by bot)
      ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx = ctx;

      return ctx.wizard.next();
    },

    async (userCtx) => {
      //Validating ctx. If user doesnt sent a text message - deleting his message.
      if (!userCtx?.message?.text) return userCtx.deleteMessage();

      const smthData = userCtx.message.text;

      //Deleting user's message. We will add it to the bot message by editing it. (ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx)
      userCtx.deleteMessage();

      //Editing message from bot (adding data from user)

      await ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx.editMessageText(
        `1. Your data: ${smthData}
        
        Send something else.`,
        {
          ...Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            [
              Markup.button.callback(`Back`, `back`),
              Markup.button.callback(`Cancel`, `cancel`),
            ],
          ]), //Back to te previous step button.
          parse_mode: "HTML",
        }
      );

      //Saved data to session storage.
      ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData = smthData;
      return ctx.wizard.next();
    },

    async (ctx) => {
      //Validating ctx. If user doesnt sent a text message - deleting his message.
      if (!userCtx?.message?.text) return userCtx.deleteMessage();

      const smthData2 = userCtx.message.text;

      //Deleting user's message. We will add it to the bot message by editing it. (ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx)
      userCtx.deleteMessage();

      //Editing message from bot (adding data from user)

      await ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx.editMessageText(
        `1. Your data: ${ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData}
        2. Your data: ${smthData2}
        
        Send something else.`,
        {
          ...Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            [
              Markup.button.callback(`Back`, `back`),
              Markup.button.callback(`Cancel`, `cancel`),
            ],
          ]), //Back to te previous step button.
          parse_mode: "HTML",
        }
      );

      //Saved data 2 to session storage.
      ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData2 = smthData2;
      return ctx.wizard.next();
    },

    async (ctx) => {
      //Validating ctx. If user doesnt sent a text message - deleting his message.
      if (!userCtx?.message?.text) return userCtx.deleteMessage();

      const smthData3 = userCtx.message.text;

      //Deleting user's message. We will add it to the bot message by editing it. (ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx)
      userCtx.deleteMessage();

      //Editing message from bot (adding data from user)

      await ctx.wizard.state.data.firstCtx.editMessageText(
        `1. Your data: ${ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData}
        2. Your data: ${ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData2}
        3. Your data: ${smthData3}
        
         End.`,
        {
          parse_mode: "HTML",
        }
      );

      //Saved data 2 to session storage.
      ctx.wizard.state.data.smthData2 = smthData2;
      return ctx.wizard.leave();
    }
  );

  //Step back
  scene.action(/^(?:back)$/i, async (ctx) => {
    //Working with previous step system...
  });

  //Leaving from scene
  scene.action(/^(?:cancel)$/i, async (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(`Leaved!`);
    return ctx.scene.leave();
  });

  return scene;
};
```

Help me, please!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.